# Window Capture playing video

Tags: capture

I captured window contents programmatically in a VB.NET app, starting from the window HDC and now it doesn't work with apps playing video (link VLC or wmplayer)

I'm using BitBilt function (I used also PrintWindow), but the contents is black if the source app is playing a video.

The capture still works if the video is played by a browser.

Is there an explanation and a way to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I found out that the problem is related to the presence of two graphic cards (Intel and Nvidia) and should be solved forcing the program to use the Intel card.
Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, so I think I probabely have to find out which driver or graphic softwar has to be repaired and reinstalled.